# How to use GraphQL queries while using nuxt-apollo?

Tags: axios, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I am trying to query the data from a `Django` endpoint which lists all my `articles` using `Graphene Django`. I followed all documentations but cannot understand how to fetch data in `vuex` action.

When using `GraphiQl` I can get the data answer. I have arranged my `nuxt.config.js`

```
apollo: {
    tokenName: "nuxt-apollo", // specify token name
    cookieAttributes: {
      expires: 7 // optional, default: 7 (days)
    },
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        errorPolicy: "all"
      }
    },
    watchLoading: "@/apollo/loadingHandler.js",
    errorHandler: "@/apollo/errorHandler.js",
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/articles/graphql/'
      }
    }
  },
```

Now In my `vuex` store, but I cannot figure how to query and use data, I tried to query as below but no success:

```
async fetchArticles({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response =  this.$axios.$get(
        'articles/graphql/',
        {
          query: query({
            query: gql`
              query Articles {
                allArticles {
                  id
                  title
                }
              }
            ` 
          }) 
        }
      )
        
    } catch (error) {
      commit('setError', error)
    }
  },
```

Can you help me to fix my query?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply install [`graphql-tag`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag) library for creating queries to send over Apollo Client.

Also you can create file named article.graphql :

```
query Articles {
    allArticles {
      id
      title
    }
 }
```

Also pass parameters to query like this:

```
query ($param: [String]) {
   //your query
}
```

And usage in store:

```
import articleQuery from './queries/article.graphql';
....
// some store action
async fetchArticles({ commit }) {
    const client = this.app.apolloProvider.clients.default;

    // Optional Param   
    // const param = format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    const queryResult = 
       await client.query({
          query: articleQuery,
          // Optional (if query contain parameter you can use)
          // variables: { param }
        });
}
```